# Colormap in Python

Tags: python, matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure, colormap

I have created a colormap in software Matlab R2014b. The code is:

```
figure, imshow(classImage,[])
colormap(gcf,parula)
```

How can I process in python/ gcolab?
thankyou for your help

Comment: that is not "creating a colormap", but just setting it. Have you tried using a search engine to find "colormap python"? The answer is there.

Comment: Also, “parula” is a proprietary color map from MATLAB, there are some copies out there if you need a close match.